# Passing parameters to event handler from a functional component without using inline syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code where I need to pass index value to the event handler which I am getting as a prop from another component. How can I achieve this without using the inline syntax, as inline syntax is not considered as a good approach since it may lead to the creation of new function each time the component re-renders?

```
const Persons = (props) => {
  return (props.persons.map((person, index) => {
    return <Person
      click={() => props.click(index)}
      name={person.name}
      age={person.age}
      key={person.id}
      changed={(event) => props.changed(event, person.id)} />
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-line anonymous function is fine in most cases, but if you want to ***not*** do that you can create a curried handler to attach.

```
const changeHandler = id => event => {...};
const clickHandler = index => () => {...};
```

This function consumes and encloses an `id` variable and returns a function that consumes an `event` object. This returned function is what elements/components will use as a callback.

Pass to component

```
<Persons click={clickHandler} change={changeHandler} />
```

And attach callback to handler

```
const Persons = (props) => {
  return (props.persons.map((person, index) => {
    return <Person
      click={props.click(index)}
      name={person.name}
      age={person.age}
      key={person.id}
      changed={props.changed(person.id)} />
  }));
}
```